# Matching a parameterless objective-c method

Tags: regex

I have written a regex to match a parameterless method in objc but it is nor working correctly. It matches methods with one parameter too.

This is the regex:

```
\-\s*\((?<RetType>.*?)\)\s*(?<FuncName>(\w+))\s*{
```

This matches all this method:

```
-(void) heyzapCheckinTapped: (id)sender {
```

I was expecting it to do not match this 1 param method just a parameterless one.

Why is it matching all the method signature in the case of one parameter?. Shouldn't it stop right before the ':' character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should escape the `{`?

Comment: I tried it before asking. Same Result. I'm using c# regex.Match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
\-\s*\((?<RetType>.*?)\)\s*
```

Matches this:

```
-(void) heyzapCheckinTapped: (id)
```

This is because right after `\s*` you have `(?<FuncName>(\w+))` (not sure why you have a capture group inside a named capture group) and so, the `.*?` will match anything until there's spaces (0 or more) followed by `\w` characters.

Laziness doesn't mean it will stop at the first occurrence of the immediate next pattern. It will still try to match if there's a possible match.

You might turn the regex into:

```
\-\s*\((?<RetType>[^)]+)\)\s*(?<FuncName>\w+)\s*{
```

`[^)]+` makes sure you're still in the first parenthesis when matching.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will have to reread this a few more times.

Comment: @Notbad If you have any query on this issue, let me know and I'll elaborate on my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think There's something  that could be wrong in your answer. You state that \-\s*\((?<RetType>.*?)\)\s* matches this -(void) heyzapCheckinTapped: (id . But for me it matches just -(void) . I have just tried it.

Comment: @Notbad See [link](http://regex101.com/r/lF7rA7) I wrapped the part mentioned in my answer between a named capture group called 'partbeingcaptured'